# Form Post with Facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Can anyone point me in the direction of how I can use a form post with the Facebook C# SDK in an MVC app? It's an iframe based Canvas application.

I have the following code

```
[HttpPost, CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = "publish_stream")]
public ActionResult Enter(FormCollection col)
{
    var fbApp = new FacebookClient(this.CurrentSession.AccessToken);

    JsonObject result = (JsonObject)fbApp.Get("me");

    long FacebookId = long.Parse(result["id"].ToString());

    //CODE TO INSERT GOES HERE

     return View();
}
```

And the form is this

```
<form action="/EnterComp/Enter" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Fields</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="Text">Text</label>

    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input id="Text" name="Text" type="text" value="" />

    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="ImagePath">ImagePath</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">

        <input type="file" name="ImagePath" id="ImagePath">

    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="VideoPath">VideoPath</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="file" name="VideoPath" id="VideoPath">

    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

But everytime I submit the form, it appears to re-authenticate - and thus lose the form collection. Now I'm sure there's something really simple I'm missing, any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I think I've answered my own question here, but in case anyone else after me looks. The solution, for me at least, was [here](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=244819).

However, if anyone can suggest anything else. Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is actually a helper for MVC forms that will fix this issue for you.

The helper goes inside your form:

Razor Syntax:

```
@Html.FacebookSignedRequest();
```

ASP.NET Syntax

```
<%=Html.FacebookSignedRequest() %>
```

All this actually does is store your signed_requeset as a hidden on your form. This way when the form is posted the Facebook authenticator will be able to reauthorize the request.