# 5.0.3 Beta can't get Form Fields when decorated with CanvasAuthorize in IE7

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using 5.0.3 beta and I can't get form fields when my controller method has a `[CanvasAuthorize( Permissions = "user_about_me")]`

If I comment out this `CanvasAuthorize` all form fields are passed correctly.  With it all I get is a signed request form field but none of the ones in the actual form.

This gets even more strange since in Chrome it works fine, but on IE 7 (have not tried others yet) it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer here helps you?

[Form Post with Facebook C# SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960552/form-post-with-faceboook-c-sdk)