# Where can i find the @Html.FacebookSignedRequest()

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have the same problem as here [Form Post with Facebook C# SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960552/form-post-with-faceboook-c-sdk)

when i try and include the  @Html.FacebookSignedRequest() i get

does not contain a definition for 'FacebookSignedRequest' and no extension method 'FacebookSignedRequest' .. missing assembly

what assembly can this helper be found in?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is present in Facebook.Web.Mvc.dll

Make sure you to have the following at top of your file

```
@using Facebook.Web.Mvc
```

or in web.config

```
<pages>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Facebook.Web.Mvc" />
    <namespaces>
<pages>
```

Comment: Yes Thank you, so obvious when you think about it. been working too hard on this project, answer just came to me while I was sleeping.